# Alamofire not available after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire in a swift file that is part of a hybrid (Obj-c/Swift) application. I added a reference to my pod file and ran 'pod install'

When I try to import Alamofire into my Swift file, I get a compile error and Alamofire is not in code completion. Here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'TheProjectName' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end
```

When I return to my Swift file, I should be able to add the following statement:

```
import Alamofire
```

but I cannot because Alamofire is not found. The message is

```
no such module 'Alamofire'
```

I have verified that Alamofire is in my pods directory and appears to have been installed correctly. There are no error messages of any kind when running 'pod install'

Any ideas or suggestions of how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: 1. I assume you are running the xcworkspace  and not the xcodeproj version
2. Did you try doing a clean and clean build folder ?

Comment: Yep, running from workspace, tried everything I know - clean, clean build folder, nothing

Comment: What are you Library/Framework/Header Search Paths ?

Comment: Are you opening `YourProject.xcworkspace` instead of `YourProject.xcodeproj`?

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple targets in your workspace? If so, you will need to add that target as well to your podfile.

Comment: Simply building the project should work. I was facing the same issue which was fixed by building the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your project before you attempt to import after pods install.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I cloned a working project that integrated with Alamofire (from CocoaPods) I encounter this same "unhooked" framework compiler error. I would perform various actions: uninstall / reinstall, open/close; close Xcode - deintegrate - delete files - install - update - open Xcode - clean, build for "generic" - build for simulator, etc. as suggested.  Never quite certain if it was going to fix the issue, but eventually it *might*.  Tonight, it was exceptionally stubborn and this is what I truly believe fixed it ...

In Xcode,

- locate the file Alamofire.swift in the Project Navigator
- delete the file from Alamofire folder under the framework (remove reference, do **NOT** toss in the trash)
- add new file (right click on Alamofire folder) and navigate to find the Alamofire.swift file

Build-to-run on Simulator (my case I used iPhone 12) and voila it compiled successfully.